# Spring dev tools properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I working on a spring-boot program that loads Data-base information from a properties file.That's fine so far, but during some debug, I find-out that the information loaded wasn`t coming from my property file but coming from some place called "dev tools local".

I know this cause I have this code that logs all properties that is been loaded :

```
 public class PropertiesLogger implements 
      ApplicationListener<ApplicationPreparedEvent> {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PropertiesLogger.class);

private ConfigurableEnvironment environment;

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationPreparedEvent event) {
    environment = event.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment();
    printProperties();
}

public void printProperties() {
    for (EnumerablePropertySource propertySource : findPropertiesPropertySources()) {
        log.info("********** " + propertySource.getName() + " **********");
        String[] propertyNames = propertySource.getPropertyNames();
        Arrays.sort(propertyNames);
        for (String propertyName : propertyNames ){
            String resolvedProperty = environment.getProperty(propertyName);
            String sourceProperty = propertySource.getProperty(propertyName).toString();
            if(resolvedProperty.equals(sourceProperty)) {
                log.info("{}={}", propertyName, resolvedProperty);
            }else {
                log.info("{}={} OVERRIDEN to {}", propertyName, sourceProperty, resolvedProperty);
            }
        }
    }
}

private List<EnumerablePropertySource> findPropertiesPropertySources() {
    List<EnumerablePropertySource> propertiesPropertySources = new LinkedList<>();
    for (PropertySource<?> propertySource : environment.getPropertySources()) {
        if (propertySource instanceof EnumerablePropertySource) {
            propertiesPropertySources.add((EnumerablePropertySource) propertySource);
        }
    }
    return propertiesPropertySources;
}
```

}

Does anyone know how do I find where this information is coming from? that is, if there is a file with those information, how do I find that file and change it?

thanks

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html and https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html